# Why is Heroku trimming trailing slashes?

Tags: php, apache, heroku, laravel-5

I have a Laravel webapp that I am developing for a Heroku environment.  On the heroku environment, if I visit a url with a trailing slash (I.E. http://example.com/) I get a 301 redirect removing the trailing slash (I.E. http://example.com).  This would be fine behavior, except that the rewrite is moving from https to http!

I've spent some time trying to reproduce the issue locally in my development environment and I cannot, which has led me to believe that the issue is with Heroku's configuration of Apache, but uploading a custom .htaccess turning RewriteEngine Off didn't stop the rewrite either.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue?

My procfile just contains`web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public` so it's quite minimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku does not perform such redirects. Apache adds slashes for directory indexes if enabled, but that's it.

Your application is doing that redirect somewhere, either in code or a `.htaccess`, and the request protocol is not preserved because the request to the dyno was HTTP - termination of SSL happens at the load balancer.

Set up your application to trust the Heroku load balancer as a proxy so it reads the request protocol from `X-Forwarded-Proto`, or change your rewrite rules to do just that.

Comment: The bit about the X-Forwarded-Proto was totally new to me and that was the reason the requests were switching protocols.  Thank you!