# heroku redirecting https urls without trailing slash to http

Tags: ruby, nginx, heroku, middleman

I have a ruby app with an Nginx config on Heroku. there are no rules for https->http or http->https for trailing slashes, however all my urls seem to make several hops unecessarily when trailing slashes are not present.

https://www.someurl.com

goes to

http://www.someurl.com/

Urls with trailing slashes work as expected. Anybody else experience this issue?

Comment: long shot... what's the value of `config.force_ssl` in your `production.rb`?

Comment: I don't have a production.rb. This is a Middleman app https://middlemanapp.com/. I'm assuming this issue is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35279994/why-is-heroku-trimming-trailing-slashes/35390428 however slightly different (reversed actually because it's a lack of trailing slashes causing the problem)

Comment: check your `application.rb` for ssl related stuff/config